# How to add editText to listView with onTextChange?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a listView with 2 editText on each row, that are using TextWatcher interface for recognizing if we changes the current text on the editText
My problem is that my adapter is very very laggy and slow. how can i handle this issue ?
here is my adapter:

```
public class AccountListInfoAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mContext;
    private ArrayList<ModelClass> accounts;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private prevClass mainActivityFragment;
    private ViewHolder holder;

    public AccountListInfoAdapter2(Activity activity, ArrayList<ModelClass> mAccountListData, prevClass mainActivityFragment) {
        this.mContext = activity;
        this.accounts = mAccountListData;
        this.mainActivityFragment = mainActivityFragment;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (accounts == null) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return accounts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_info_row, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                assert view != null;
                setViews(view);
                view.setTag(holder);
                holder.emailAddress.setText(accounts.get(position).getEmail());
                holder.fullName.setText(accounts.get(position).getFullName());

            holder.fullName.setId(position);
            holder.emailAddress.setId(position);


            //Check if full name has been changed
            holder.fullName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (s.length() != count) {
                        if (!accounts.get(position).getFullName().equals(s.toString())) {
                            accounts.get(position).setFullName(s.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (!accounts.get(position).getFullName().equals(s.toString())) {
                        accounts.get(position).setFullName(s.toString());
                    }
                }
            });


            //Check if email name has been changed
            holder.emailAddress.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(s.length() != count) {
                        if (!accounts.get(position).getEmail().equals(s.toString())){
                            accounts.get(position).getEmail(s.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (!accounts.get(position).getEmail().equals(s.toString())) {
                        accounts.get(position).getEmail(s.toString());
                    }
                }
            });

        return view;
    }


    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView emailAddress;
        EditText fullName;
    }


    public void setViews(View view){
        holder.emailAddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.accountInfoProfileEmailAddress);
        holder.fullName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.accountInfoFullName);
    }


}
```

Comment: you are not reusing the views in your adapter: see `convertView` parameter

Comment: I don't know how to do it properly

Comment: then read about view reusing in the adapters, [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/) for example, or [here](http://android-decoded.blogspot.com/2011/12/so-what-exactly-is-convertview.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.fullName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() != count) 
                {

                    if (!accounts.get(position).getFullName().equals(s.toString())) {
                        //accounts.get(position).setFullName(s.toString());
                        ((MainActivity)context).changeListViewItem(position , s.toString);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!accounts.get(position).getFullName().equals(s.toString())) {
                    //accounts.get(position).setFullName(s.toString());
                    ((MainActivity)context).changeListViewItem(position , s.toString);
                }
            }
        });
```

Add this function on main activity

```
public void changeListViewItem(int position , String text)
{
    Log.e("" , ""+position);
    Log.e("" , ""+text);
    refreshAdapter();
}
```

Comment: What is in the "refreshAdapter" method?

Comment: refreshAdapter() is your method where you can customize your adapter with position and text

Answer (score 0):

1.`addTextChangedListener` can be add repeat.

U can try to add a log in `onTextChanged`.

Watch how many times it logs when u type a `char`.

When u use `addTextChangedListener`, add a `tag`.

2.U should try to use `ViewHolder` to help u.